# OpenVPN: internet lost

Tags: 14.04, internet, openvpn

I have installed OpenVPN on my computer which is running Ubuntu 14.04. Basically when I try to run OpenVPN, I lose access to the Internet.
I tried to turn off ufw,to  change my nameserver and also I have tried to reinstall using the following instructions  https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos
Nothing helped.
What can I do?

Comment: How do you try to run OpenVPN? Through the command line, or with Network Manager? What VPN provider do you use, what settings do you have, and what exactly happens when you try to connect?

Comment: I have tried to use this command form shell  sudo openvpn --config example.ovpn and also tried to use Network Manager. I tried to use config files from vpnbook.com and http://www.vpngate.net/en/. It normally connects and says Initialization Sequence Completed.
I don't quite understand what kind of settings you want me provide.